# How to prevent duplicate code in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I Have a model called HttpLogModel.I insert response and request and duration in Httplogs table after any http request client. I have used this code in different places.

```
  $startTime = microtime(true);

  // this part is dynamic code 
  $client =  Http::get($url); 
  //Or
  $client = Http::get($url, ['name' => 'Taylor','page' => 1,]); 
  //Or 
  $client = Http::asForm()->post($url, ['name' => 'Taylor','page' => 1,]); 
  /// Or any http client request

  $durationTime = microtime(true) - $startTime;

  if ($client->clientError() || $client->serverError()) {
      HttpLogModel::addErrorLog(
        $provider, $step, $data, $client->toException()->getMessage(), $url, $durationTime
     );

     if ($client->status() == 401) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException();
     }

     if ($client->serverError()) {
        throw new ServerException();
     }

     throw new ProviderException('ProviderException');
  }

   HttpLogModel::addLog(
      $provider, $step, $client, $url, $durationTime
   );

   return $client->json();
  }
```

How to prevent duplicate code?

Comment: Create a function and put that code in it. Where you put that function is up to you: app/helpers.php or a special class for code just as this.

Comment: You could also go for something similar to a template method pattern or simply encapsulate the code (dynamic part in your code) into a function and pass it to a function that outlines all the logic and logging surrounding it.

Comment: A good place might also be a global middleware

Comment: Not sure about functions but you can have service calls. The benefits: easy to mock while testing, extendable and you can use laravel's DI to resolve them for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into repository pattern. What it basically is, it's a class, in a different Namespace, where you inject the model and create all sorts of functions using the model inside of it.

The trick is that each time you need a certain query, you use the repository and each time you tend to duplicate, you put the queries in the repository and use it that way.

For that I recommend you:https://asperbrothers.com/blog/implement-repository-pattern-in-laravel/
I encourage you to try it. It sounds fancy but it is nothing more than another class.

If you find it confusing, you have another solution.

Take that query that you have duplicated and put it into a static method. For example, lets say you have the following class:

```
Class SomeModel extends Model {

}
```

and you query it in different places like this:

```
$someCollection = SomeModel::Where('column', $value)->where('other_column', $otherValue)->get();
```

For example you can use this into a controller but then need it into a command and find yourself duplicating it. Now, you can go to that class

```
Class SomeModel extends Model {

}
```

add

```
public static function something() {
    return SomeModel::Where('column', $value)->where('other_column', $otherValue)->get();
}
```

and then go in each place you have use it and replace it with

```
SomeModel::something();
```